# How can I disable a single module in local.xml?

Tags: magento-1.9, local.xml, wordpress, third-party-module

Our live Magento site has the *FishPig* WordPress plugin in place, however in development this should be disabled completely as the WordPress site isn't there.

I understand that this can be disabled in `app/etc/modules/Fishpig_Wordpress.xml` but I don't want this to get committed in to Git.

Is there a way which the module can be disabled (or enabled) in a specific environment using `local.xml` or similar?

Answer (score 0):

You can either write a script that is executed when receiving a new code from git.

Or you can simply add the `app/etc/modules/Fishpig_Wordpress.xml` to your .gitignore file so and make sure it isn't in your git repo.